# html canvas - enlarge stroke width on donut chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, donut-chart

I followed a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RgLAU/1/

and made a donut chart. Right now the donut chart has really tiny strokes in white separating each segment of the donut. For instance, in the picture below, you can see (barely) that there are 6 sections to the donut, delineated by white strokes.

[image]

My problem is that I want to increase the thickness of those lines without increasing the thickness of the chart overall, such that the breaks look a little more like this:

[image]

Here's my JS. Any help greatly appreciated.:

```
var donutVm = this;

donutVm.donutHeight = donutVm.donutHeightConfig || 150;
donutVm.donutWidth = donutVm.donutWidthConfig || 150;
donutVm.donutRadius = donutVm.donutRadiusConfig || 50;

if (CommunityConfig.conversionContestActionId) {
    ActionService.get({ id: CommunityConfig.conversionContestActionId, type: 'action' }).$promise.then(function (response) {
        if (CommunityConfig.conversionContestConversionCountTarget) donutVm.totalConversions = CommunityConfig.conversionContestConversionCountTarget;
        var action = response;
        if (action.linkReference) {
            action.getContextFromLinkReference(action.linkReference, function (error, context) {
                var conversionsMade = context.conversionCount;

                var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
                var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

                function drawDonutChart(canvas)
                {
                    donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, donutVm.lineWidth, donutVm.strokeStyle, donutVm.from, donutVm.to = null;
                    donutVm.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
                        donutVm.x = x;
                        donutVm.y = y;
                        donutVm.radius = radius;
                        donutVm.from = from;
                        donutVm.to = to;
                        donutVm.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                        donutVm.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
                    };

                    donutVm.draw = function(data) {
                        canvas.beginPath();
                        canvas.lineWidth = donutVm.lineWidth;
                        canvas.strokeStyle = donutVm.strokeStyle;
                        canvas.arc(donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, donutVm.from, donutVm.to);
                        canvas.stroke();
                        var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
                        var parts = data.parts.pt;
                        var colors = data.colors.cs;
                        var df = 1.5 * Math.PI;

                        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
                            canvas.beginPath();
                            canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                            canvas.arc(donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100));
                            canvas.stroke();
                            df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
                        }
                    }
                }

                var sections = {"pt": []};
                var sectionColors = {"cs": []};
                var emptyColor = "lightgrey";
                var madeColor = CommunityConfig.styles.buttonColor;
                var sectionPercentage = 100/donutVm.totalConversions;

                if (conversionsMade == donutVm.totalConversions) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < conversionsMade; y++) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(emptyColor);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var y = 0; y < conversionsMade; y++) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(madeColor);
                    }

                    while (sectionColors.cs.length < donutVm.totalConversions) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(emptyColor);
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < donutVm.totalConversions; i++){
                    sections.pt.push(sectionPercentage);
                }

                var data = {
                    numberOfParts: donutVm.totalConversions,
                    parts: sections,
                    colors: sectionColors
                };

                var drawDonut = new drawDonutChart(chart);
                donutVm.set(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, donutVm.donutRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, 10, "#fff");
                donutVm.draw(data);
                donutVm.donutFinished = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var donutVm = this;

donutVm.donutHeight = donutVm.donutHeightConfig || 150;
donutVm.donutWidth = donutVm.donutWidthConfig || 150;
donutVm.donutRadius = donutVm.donutRadiusConfig || 50;

if (CommunityConfig.conversionContestActionId) {
    ActionService.get({ id: CommunityConfig.conversionContestActionId, type: 'action' }).$promise.then(function (response) {
        if (CommunityConfig.conversionContestConversionCountTarget) donutVm.totalConversions = CommunityConfig.conversionContestConversionCountTarget;
        var action = response;
        if (action.linkReference) {
            action.getContextFromLinkReference(action.linkReference, function (error, context) {
                var conversionsMade = context.conversionCount;

                var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
                var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

                function drawDonutChart(canvas)
                {
                    donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, donutVm.lineWidth, donutVm.strokeStyle, donutVm.from, donutVm.to = null;
                    donutVm.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
                        donutVm.x = x;
                        donutVm.y = y;
                        donutVm.radius = radius;
                        donutVm.from = from;
                        donutVm.to = to;
                        donutVm.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                        donutVm.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
                    };

                    donutVm.draw = function(data) {
                        canvas.beginPath();
                        canvas.lineWidth = donutVm.lineWidth;
                        canvas.strokeStyle = donutVm.strokeStyle;
                        canvas.arc(donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, donutVm.from, donutVm.to);
                        canvas.stroke();
                        var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
                        var parts = data.parts.pt;
                        var colors = data.colors.cs;
                        var spacer = 2 * 0.05
                        var df = (1.5 + spacer) * Math.PI;

                        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
                            canvas.beginPath();
                            canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                            canvas.arc(donutVm.x, donutVm.y, donutVm.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100) - (2 * spacer);
                            canvas.stroke();
                            df += (Math.PI * 2) * ((parts[i] / 100) + (2 * spacer));
                        }
                    }
                }

                var sections = {"pt": []};
                var sectionColors = {"cs": []};
                var emptyColor = "lightgrey";
                var madeColor = CommunityConfig.styles.buttonColor;
                var sectionPercentage = 100/donutVm.totalConversions;

                if (conversionsMade == donutVm.totalConversions) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < conversionsMade; y++) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(emptyColor);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var y = 0; y < conversionsMade; y++) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(madeColor);
                    }

                    while (sectionColors.cs.length < donutVm.totalConversions) {
                        sectionColors.cs.push(emptyColor);
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < donutVm.totalConversions; i++){
                    sections.pt.push(sectionPercentage);
                }

                var data = {
                    numberOfParts: donutVm.totalConversions,
                    parts: sections,
                    colors: sectionColors
                };

                var drawDonut = new drawDonutChart(chart);
                donutVm.set(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, donutVm.donutRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, 10, "#fff");
                donutVm.draw(data);
                donutVm.donutFinished = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use smaller angles when drawing the arcs for the sections.
In this fiddle, I made each section 1 percent smaller in order to have visible gaps: http://jsfiddle.net/a7mh9wcv/

`canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * ((parts[i] - 1) / 100));`

Another way is to actually draw the gaps as lines: http://jsfiddle.net/jq2nhate/

This has to be done after the sections are drawn so the sections don't override the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to add a space in between all parts by diminishing all parts by a small percentage. Of course that means that you would have to check for a minimum percentage to display an arc for an item. I did not spent much time on making a complete solution.

You still have to:

1. add some checks on minimum arc length
2. make that spacing another setting in that "set function"

The following is what I tested in your JsFiddle link you shared (look at the line where the canvas.arc function is used: "df + (Math.PI * 2) * ((parts[i] - 0.5) / 100)"):

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
    var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawdountChart(canvas)
    {

        this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.lineWidth , this.strockStyle , this.from , this.to = null;
        this.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.from=from;
            this.to= to;
            this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            this.strockStyle = strockStyle; 
        }

        this.draw = function(data)
        {
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
            canvas.arc(this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.from , this.to);
            canvas.stroke();
            var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
            var parts = data.parts.pt;
            var colors = data.colors.cs;
            var df = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i<numberOfParts; i++)
            {
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
                canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * ((parts[i] - 0.5) / 100));
                canvas.stroke();
                df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
            }
        }
    }
    var data = 
        {
            numberOfParts: 4,
            parts:{"pt": [20 , 30 , 25 , 25]},//percentage of each parts 
            colors:{"cs": ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]}//color of each part
        };

    var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
    drawDount.set(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, 20, "#fff");
    drawDount.draw(data);
```

I basically removed half a percent of all part but kept the "df" variable intact.